# KafkaStreams is not running. State is ERROR

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I have a Kafka consumer class that listens to events and perform join between events (Order, Customer) and store them in a materialized view. I created another class to access state store when REST call received. But I am getting 
**java.lang.IllegalStateException: KafkaStreams is not running. State is ERROR.**  I tried to assign **application.server** property, it didn't work. Class [EventsListener](https://github.com/pavankjadda/KafkaStream-CQRS-EventSourcing/blob/master/src/main/java/com/kafkastream/service/EventsListener.java) joins events and class [StateStoreService](https://github.com/pavankjadda/KafkaStream-CQRS-EventSourcing/blob/master/src/main/java/com/kafkastream/service/StateStoreService.java) queries events. Code uploaded to [Github](https://github.com/pavankjadda/KafkaStream-CQRS-EventSourcing) for reference.

Based on this discussion https://confluentcommunity.slack.com/archives/C48AHTCUQ/p1500079616414627  and below notes from Matt, I deleted application.server property.

```
The error means, that a consumer subscribed to topic "source-topic" but got partition "test-name-0" (ie, partition 0 from topic "test-name") assigned. Of course, the consumer did not expect to get a partition of topic "test-name" as it never subscribed to it and this is fails.
In Streams, this can happen if you have two application instances of the same application, and both subscribe to different topics (what is not allowed).
Ie, all instanced of an application must have the same processing logic and must subscribe to the same topics. This implies that if you want to consume 2 topics, all instances need to read both topics.
```

But I still can not read from the state store. Code stuck at thread.sleep() method.

Exception:

```
Exception in thread "cqrs-streams-5d77fdb3-f75e-443d-b7b7-fabedcbc483f-StreamThread-1" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Assigned partition order-0 for non-subscribed topic regex pattern; subscription pattern is 
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.SubscriptionState.assignFromSubscribed(SubscriptionState.java:195)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator.onJoinComplete(ConsumerCoordinator.java:225)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator.joinGroupIfNeeded(AbstractCoordinator.java:367)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator.ensureActiveGroup(AbstractCoordinator.java:316)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator.poll(ConsumerCoordinator.java:295)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.pollOnce(KafkaConsumer.java:1146)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.poll(KafkaConsumer.java:1111)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.pollRequests(StreamThread.java:851)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.runOnce(StreamThread.java:808)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.runLoop(StreamThread.java:774)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.run(StreamThread.java:744)
java.lang.IllegalStateException: KafkaStreams is not running. State is ERROR.
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.KafkaStreams.validateIsRunning(KafkaStreams.java:312)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.KafkaStreams.allMetadata(KafkaStreams.java:934)
    at com.kafkastream.service.StateStoreService.waitUntilStoreIsQueryable(StateStoreService.java:105)
    at com.kafkastream.service.StateStoreService.getCustomerOrders(StateStoreService.java:59)
    at com.kafkastream.web.EventsController.getCustomerOrders(EventsController.java:101)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:209)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:136)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:102)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:877)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:783)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:991)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:925)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:974)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:866)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:635)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:851)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:109)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:81)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:496)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:803)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:790)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1459)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: Are you using version .11 or newer?

Comment: Yes. I am using confluent v4.1

Comment: The error `java.lang.IllegalStateException: KafkaStreams is not running. State is ERROR.` indicates, that your `KafkaStreams` instance crashed and thus, you cannot query the stores. You need to figure out, why it crashes first and fix the root cause. Check the log files that should contain the actual error that made KafkaStreams die.

Comment: You are right matt. I got this whole thing wrong. I figured out the issue and posted steps to tackle this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was caused by the wrong approach. Rest Proxy should start by consumer class and second class should get data from REST API started by jetty server

1. Start REST proxy from EventsListener class (just execute EventsListener class)
2. All the customer orders should be accessible from http://localhost:8095/customer-orders/all
3. Start SpringBoot class and try to access http://localhost:8090/customerOrders/CU9978. This should connect to REST proxy started by EventsListener class.

Answer (score 1):

"KafkaStreams is not running. State is ERROR"
I got this error because i didn't defined sink topic of my streaming app. When I defined the sink topic. I was able to resolve this error.